# appending pandas rows with the nearest point of each row in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 150 rows and 4 columns, i wish to append each row with a vector from the dataframe that has the minimum distance from all the other points(rows). The result would be a dataframe with shape 150x8.

```
[concat pandas dataframe][1]
```

```
`pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1, join="inner")`
```

Df2 needs to be df1 rearranged in a way that every row of df2 has minimum distance of the df1 equivalent and not just shuffled as in the picture.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjyE2.png

Comment: You can do an [`asof` merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

Comment: Could you post a sample data and the code you attempted?

Comment: please provide sample data and your attempted code with details

Answer (score 0):

````
from scipy.spatial import distance
m=[]
for i in range(len(df1)):
    u=[]
    for j in range(len(df1)):
        u.append(distance.euclidean(df1.iloc[i],df1.iloc[j]))
    m.append(u.index(sorted(u)[1]))
pd.concat([df1,df1.iloc[m].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1, join="inner")```
````